# Crear una función para manipular cadenas de caracteres en C

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de crear una función para eliminar el caracter `\n` de una cadena de texto, sin éxito hasta el momento, por lo que quisiera que me explicaran como solucionar los errores que prsenta mi implementación.

Tengo este programa:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define NOMBRE 32
#define CALLE 32

char cadena[](char string[]);

int main() {
  char Nombre[NOMBRE];
  char Calle[CALLE];

  printf("\nNombre: "); fgets(Nombre, NOMBRE, stdin);
  printf("\nCalle: "); fgets(Calle, CALLE, stdin);

  printf("\n\n%s \t %s", cadena[Nombre], cadena[Calle]);

}

char cadena[](char string[]) {
  if(string[strlen(string)-1] == '\n')
    string[strlen(string)-1] = 0;
  return string;
}
```

El compilador *gcc 10* me marca dos errores relacionados con la función `char cadena[](char string[]);`

1. la ve como una declaración de un *array (arreglo) de funciones*, pero quiero que sea una función que acepta un arreglo cualquiera.
2. falta algo en la definición de la función.

```sh
ej14_4.c:10:6: error: declaration of ‘cadena’ as array of functions
   10 | char cadena[](char string[]);
      |      ^~~~~~
ej14_4.c:30:30: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
   30 | char cadena[](char string[]) {
      |                              ^
```

### ¿Cómo debo definir la función para que haga lo que quiero?

Comment: no es char[] cadena??? estas poniendo despues del nombre de la funcion una declaracion de array?

Comment: El tipo de valor de retorno deberia ser `char*`.. es decir, debe retornar la direccion del primer elemento del *array*..

Answer (score 1):

El error que estas teniendo se da porque cuando en c escribís algo como cadena[] estas diciendo implícitamente que es un arreglo.

Entonces cuando intestas definir la función

> char cadena[](char string[]);

estas diciendo que cadena es un arreglo y al mismo tiempo es el nombre de la función, de ahi el error.

Si querés que la funcion cadena devuelva un string basta con que la definas como

> char* cadena (char* string);